# Creating listview icons on the fly on VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, image, dynamic

Is that possible? I want to pass my custom color as a parameter and I want to receive an Image (rectangle for example).

```
Public Function createIcon(ByVal c As Color) As Bitmap
    Dim g As Graphics
    Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(c)
    g.FillRectangle(Brush, New Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20))
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(20, 20, g)
    Return bmp
End Function
```

I tried this way and couldn't success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **`Bitmap`**: A canvas (in memory) that contains an image.
- **`Graphics`**: A tool set that allows you to draw on an associated canvas.

With this in mind, here is the solution:

```
Public Function CreateIcon(ByVal c As Color, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Bitmap
    Dim icon As New Bitmap(x, y)

    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(icon)
        Using b As New SolidBrush(c)
            g.FillRectangle(b, New Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20))
        End Using
    End Using

    Return icon
End Function
```

The `Using` blocks here merely serve the purpose of disposing the graphics resources properly (by automatically calling their `Dispose` method at the end of the block). You *need* to do this, otherwise you will leak graphics resources.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll use that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it. I am going to share what I did just in case.

```
Public Function createIcon(ByVal c As Color, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Bitmap
    createIcon = New Bitmap(x, y)
    For i = 0 To x - 1
        For j = 0 To y - 1
            If i = 0 Or j = 0 Or i = x - 1 Or j = y - 1 Then
                createIcon.SetPixel(i, j, Color.Black)
            Else
                createIcon.SetPixel(i, j, c)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return createIcon
End Function
```

This function will give you a colored rectangle with black border.

Comment: This is not how you should be drawing your images.  See Konrad's answer.